# Bundle vs Minification,Which one is the best

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundler, minify

I would like to know about which one of the following way is better.

Bundle the css files and then use :

```
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/BootStrap/css").Include(
                        "~/BootStrap/css/bootstrap.css",
                        "~/BootStrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css"));
```

**OR**

Use *.min file directly is as below :

```
<link href="~/BootStrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/BootStrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I would expect the explanation for performance wise and also as best practices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bundling is better because it not only minifies the included files but it packages them together in one resource which translates to one request to the server instead of multiple requests, one for each file.

In terms of best practice, using Bundling is part of the MVC convention so I would consider that approach to be best practice.

Comment: @Sampath Absolutely, passing in an already minified file shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: But it won't work.I have tried it.Bundling totally ignore the min files.It only accepts non min files.Do you have any idea ?

Comment: @Sampath It may depend on your build mode, Debug usually includes the full files whereas Release includes the minified versions.  Does your Bundle look like the one you included in your question?  There you are not including the minified versions.

Comment: Yep,Actually I have tested on debug mode.Instead of the above code I have given the min files with bundle.But non of the bootstrap files  loaded.After that I have changed as above and then everything works fine.

Comment: @Sampath Nevermind, it is the `<compilation>` element in the web.config that dictates which version is used.  You must set the `debug` attribute to `false`.  However, I think this might only affect bundles that use the {version} wildcard in there name.

Comment: If we not use min inside the bundling,will it automatically do for that on release mode (I mean use min file for production) ?In other words Will bundling do the minification task also on release mode other than the bundling task ?

Comment: @Sampath It should do both when the application is deployed and the `debug` attribute of the `<compilation>` element of the web.config is set to `false`.

Comment: Be careful with bundling. For mobile visitors, you don't want to be transferring a massive bundle of stuff they don't need. You should be looking at the requested URL and serving custom bundles per page.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is difficult to say that which one is better. Both have there own pros and cons.

Check **[this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification)**:-

> **Bundling**
>
> Bundling is a new feature in ASP.NET 4.5 that makes it easy to combine
>   or bundle multiple files into a single file. You can create CSS,
>   JavaScript and other bundles. Fewer files means fewer HTTP requests
>   and that can improve first page load  performance.
>
> **Minification**
>
> Minification performs a variety of different code optimizations to
>   scripts or css, such as removing unnecessary white space and comments
>   and shortening variable names to one character.

Answer (score 0):

Use bundling with caution.

While it does decrease the number of http-requests, it makes browser cache (and proxy cache, and CDN cache and whatever cache you use) **less usable**.

Say, you have `scriptA.js` and `scriptB.js`. Some pages use `A`, some pages use `B`, some pages use both `A` ***and*** `B`

With bundler its three different scripts. Without bundling it's two.